# How can I programatically prevent a file on a linux file system from being edited for a limited time

Tags: linux, file, permissions, file-permissions

I don't know if this is even possible, but I want to write a program that locks a file on a linux file system for editing for a certain period (e.g. an hour). Even super users shouldn't be allowed to edit it during this time, but it should always be possible to read the file. Is this possible? If so, please explain in general terms how I would go about this. The program could be written in any language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chattr +i file_name` command, this will prevent to change file, but it could be possible to read it.
 And then you can revert this change back `chattr -i file_name`.

Example:

`chattr +i README.md; sleep 3600; chattr -i  README.md`

Comment: @Mischa specified even `root` should be prevented from making changes to the given file.

Comment: `chattr` prevent root making changes ))

Comment: We should not forget root is setting this flag. So, it is not like we are protecting this file from root.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add and configure security module like [SELinux](https://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page). You will be able to restrict the access to access to files to users and applications including the `root`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.

Comment: SELinux can do lot more, but takes some effort to setup and configure and validate the functional requirements. So, did not give you the steps.